# Button change position because of auto layout

Tags: ios, autolayout, xcode8, swift2

I have a problems when I went from Xcode7 to Xcode8 and swift 2.2 to swift 2.3.

I have many errors : https://gyazo.com/38389de1428b0e35a6d2744df90b7c18 or [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Muecg.png)

However, my code compile and the app run it. But the pictures are buttons are completely shifted or not even appear.
Yet, when I click into space (where the button should be normal) its action is created , it is just invisible.

I think the errors are related to the image shift , could you help me please ?

Comment: Are you sure you are not switching to swift 3 acutally ?

Comment: No i'm sure to selected Swift 2.3